# Android: Turn screen ON and notify user

Tags: android, notifications

I have some Intent. When intent fires, I want to send a popup notification like an AlertBox and turn screen ON to let User see the notification immediately (I mean without showing a lockscreen).

If you've used, for example, HandcentSMS then you understand what I mean (like a popup notification when accept a message)

How to organize this? Any code examples? What kind of permissions I have to use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [KeyguardLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock.html) will do what you want: popup your notification and then call `disableKeyguard`, then re-enable when the user is done or after you time out.

Security-wise it is a little risky, but there you go.

Comment: could some one tell me how to achieve this tricky thing ?? I just want to show some alert box as a notification at some particular point of time. ON the LOCK SCREEN.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
//Do whatever you need right here
wl.release();
```

Comment: I've already tried this. My screen waked up but I have lock screen instead of my AlertBox (or my activity.. or just something mine). I don't want lock screen. I want show an Activity!

Comment: i'm pretty sure you have to show a lock because that's kind of the whole point of the lock. what if a user leaves a phone unattended or loses it, and your app turns the screen on without lock? then someone could potentially use saved credit card information or login to the owner's accounts.

Answer (score 5):

Your activity should have the following code in onCreate() implementation:

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

      setContentView( R.layout.myLayout);

      // rest of initialization
}
```

You invoke the activity using an intent. Here is an example:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);

startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

context.startActivity(startIntent);
```