# PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and ON_AFTER_RELEASE doesn't turn screen on

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I created a BroadcastReceiver to turn the screen on from an AlarmManager. Here is the code of my `OnReceive`.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.i("", "OnReceive");

    // Initializes the PowerManager.
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) arg0
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    // Wakes device.
    WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                    | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                    | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "Stretching");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    wakeLock.release();
    wakeLock = null;

    // Calls activity.
    Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, TrainingActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    arg0.startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem occurs because `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` is deprecated, so I tried to use `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`, but then the screen doesn't turn on. What should I use instead?
I searched this [How to turn screen on during partial wake lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352911/how-to-turn-screen-on-during-partial-wake-lock) but it is also using `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`.

Comment: same here on android lollipop  it does nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the deprecated `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` (and be prepared for your app to potentially no longer work in the future), or do not write the app. `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` specifically does not turn on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the FULL_WAKE_LOCK has been deprecated in favour of battery energy saving.

The only plausible workaround is to test for android version and if the version is earlier than KitKat i.e. Lollipop and up (up till KitKat FULL_WAKE_LOCK has been working fine but deprecated in API LEVEL 17) you can use FULL_WAKE_LOCK otherwise use PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK. Like this:

```
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
        (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT ? PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK : PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK) |
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
        PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "Some Tag");

    wakeLock.acquire(10000);
```

Hope that helps!