# Finish empty activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to turn screen on using an activity.
I reached my goal, but the activity stays alive.
If I use finish method, it doesn't get closed.

Note: it doesn't work even if I setContentView(...my xml...);

```
package it.android.smartscreenon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class AccendiSchermo extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
                finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen after the screen turns on?

Comment: just want to use this activity to turn on screen, so I want to close after displaying it.

Comment: why are you turning the screen on if you don't have something to show the user?

Comment: what happens if you move `finish()` to `onStart()`?

Comment: Because my app needs to turn on the display at a certain moment.

Comment: if I move move finish() to onStart() it doesn't turn on screen anymore

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?  Creating an `Activity` just to turn the screen on seems pointless.  Also the `Activity` would need the screen on for a user to start it.

Comment: If I call a wakelock to turn screen on, the display timeout is killed. I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`System.exit(0);`
in place of 
`finish();`

Comment: it doesn't turn screen on anymore

Comment: Didnt you ask for **but the activity stays alive. If I use finish method, it doesn't get closed.** I answered that on how to close your activity. Maybe you can rephrase your question.

Comment: I did not -1 but yes, I want it to show activity before closing it, not closing it without showing anything

Comment: Will the following help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your `finish();` function
in the

```
 @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow(){
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Log.d("MyLog", "InActivity->onAttachedToWindow");
    finish();
}
```