# How make mobile go sleeping programmatically

Tags: java, android, standby, powermanager

I need to do an application that turn off the mobile screen and go to sleep programmatically. For example if screen is on for more than 5 minutes without user_present, I should turn it off. 
I tried to use PowerManager (goToSleep() function should do exactly what I want, but it seems not working):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) m_context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);


  if (pm.isScreenOn() )
   {
    pm.goToSleep(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000
   }
```

I have the following permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
```

It throws an exception:
java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10068 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.
but I have this permission in my manifest.

Is there another method for doing this, without rooting my phone?

Comment: You could take a look at this and see if its of any use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android.permission.DEVICE_POWER` is granted only to system apps, third party apps do not get this permission.

If you are not holding wakelock and if you reduce `SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT` , then you should be able to achieve going to sleep automatically after 5 mins

Comment: in fact, that's what application do, if someone hold wakelock without releasing it whithin 5 minutes I should turn off device, to save battery power.By reducing SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT I don't know if I'll resolve the problem.

Comment: If say email app is holding the wakelock, then any third party app should not be able to make phone go to sleep, that would break the functionality, So I dont think that is possible.