# How to escape SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT set to ridiculously low value causing instant off?

Tags: android

So, I was reading this:
[Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)
and I tried this code:

```
        params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        params.screenBrightness = 0;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

I followed it up with

```
        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 100);
```

And yes, it turned the screen off.

and now while I imagined that this would set the screen to turn off 100 milliseconds from when it was called.... it really seems that this sets the global time out setting to "in 100 ms..." all around. Even when my app is not running. End result is that I turn on the phone, and it turns off in 0.1 second. So you can't do anything. D'oh.

Ok, yes, it SAYS settings.system right in the code, so I'm an idiot. That's fine. ;)

So battery out, and after the phone (Galaxy S3) turns on, I swipe my pattern, and it turns off the screen in 0.1 second. Press power, turns off the screen in 0.1 second. So it appears to be doing exactly what I *told* it to do, which, I can't blame it for.

So how might I escape this endless loop? No amount of "on-and-swipe-screen" is enough for it to register activity.

Worst news: I'm not sure Developer/Allow USB debugging is enabled. It's set to "media storage" right now. I can still USB connect, and browse all files.

Comment: Now, I can do a hard reset to get into some of the boot/recovery stuff. I can start up the ADB updater there. However, with I query "ADB devices" I get back that the state is in "sideload", not "device". Each time I attempt adb shell, I get "error: closed" coming back. Perhaps the bootloader is some limited adb connection? It seems that just about the only commands that work are kill-server and start-server.

Comment: Without USB debugging, only option you have is hard reset.

Comment: End result: with the boot/recovery loader, I was at least able to verify that my computer had a proper ADB connection, after downloading a ADB USB driver for samsung phones.

I was then able to get a full shell going... thank goodness, I *HAD* enabled USB debugging way back when. I wrote new code that undid my mistake, installed it, then invoked it via the shell 'am' command. Poof! everything worked again.

Interestingly, the phone shows up as "device" when booted fully, but only "sideload" when connected during the boot/management. So, whatever they have for that setup, you can't get shell.