# How to turn off the device screen light when a specific process has completed?

Tags: android

I have uploaded some data on Amazon so when process is going on, I use `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`  but after all processes are done I want to turn off the screen light again. How is it possible?

Comment: you can refer the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-   programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear flags, that you added, by using getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#clearFlags%28int%29

Comment: after setcontentview() it will be work ?? because i wrote above addFlags before setcontentview().

Comment: actually i also know about this but some one told me that it only write before setcontantview(); hahahaha so i didn't use this but thanks dude