# How to make screen turn on when motion sensor detects something?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to turn screen on when motion sensor detects than phone is moved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a way. [Gravity Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plexnor.gravityscreenofffree).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider something like this

```
//implement SensorEventListener
public class SensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
......

SensorManager sensorMan = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

sensorMan.registerListener(context, sensor,
    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

@Override
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

     if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

      }
     //Or some other sensor.
  }
```

There's more info in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is for turning on screen,

```
    public void turnOnScreen() {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!powerManager.isScreenOn()) {
            PowerManager.WakeLock screenWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(  PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                                                   | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
            screenWakeLock.acquire();
            screenWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
```