# Display turns on programmatically android

Tags: android, sleep-mode

I am developing an application in which i have to show the pop up after an hour till my device goes in sleep mode I am using this code but not working:

```
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

and forcefully active sleep mode using:

```
window.clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

Both not working.

Comment: you want to lock screen display?

Comment: How wake you your phone? Which idea are you using? What executes this code?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically