# Sleep android for 10 seconds

Tags: android, sleep

Is there a way to sleep android phone for 10 seconds and wake it up automatically?

Other details: I have SU access to the device and these devices have android version above 4.4

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     private PowerManager powerManager;
     private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

     public void turnOnScreen(){
         // turn on screen
         Log.v("MyActivity", "ON!");
         wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
         wakeLock.acquire();
    }

     @TargetApi(21) //Suppress lint error for PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK
     public void turnOffScreen(){
         // turn off screen
         Log.v("MyActivity", "OFF!");
         wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
        // start a timer to count when its done call turnOnScreen
         wakeLock.acquire();
    }
```

also in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Comment: Is there a way for Android 4.4 (API level 19)?

Comment: yes try this ,, but its not turn off its dim at its top -->
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = this.getWindow().getAttributes();

/**Seems Like Turn off: */
params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
//TODO Store original brightness value
params.screenBrightness = 0.1f;
this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);  //to show it wakes up again use params.screenBrightness = 0.9f;

Comment: your solution does not seem to work (I have tried with Android 5.1)

Comment: aaa then try one of these options and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically