# Turn screen off programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm working in an app that needs to to do any of this actions:

- Lock the device
- Put the device in sleep mode
- Turn off the screen

How can I achieve this?

Found  this option, but it requires the proximity sensor to be in "near" state to turn off the screen:

```
 mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PROXIMITY_SCREEN_OFF_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
 mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt Android lets you do this. In any case, you could try your luck with [Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41968655/962089) if the conditions are acceptable and it works on supported devices/OS versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app is a  [device admin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) you can lock the screen with [DevicePolicyManager.lockNow()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow())

You can use this snippet (after setting the Device Admin part):

```
DevicePolicyManager manager = ((DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE));
manager.lockNow();
```

Comment: Does that actually turn the screen off or just lock the phone? The way I saw it, the question was focused around the third point (and all three together are too broad for one question)

Comment: It does both, actually. It turns the screen off and locks the device.

Comment: This requires a deprecated "device admin" option. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not that I'm aware :(

Comment: deprecated what @Addev? this is still working correctly